# How to render a JSX component for each item in array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to render one jsx component for each item in an array.

```js
import { ListView } from './components'; // Custom component

const array = ["item1","item2","item3"];

export default function App() {
    return(
      <div>
        {/* Here i want to render a <ListView /> component for each of the items in the array. */}
     </div>
   );
}
```

Here there are 3 items in the array so i want to render 3 different  components.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use map method:

```
return (
 <div>{ array.map(item => <ListView key={item} item={item} /> }</div>
)
```

Comment: you are not passing `item` to `ListView`

Comment: lol, react has so beautiful code :D

Comment: @thedude yes becuse i don't now the what is inside of ListView. I just want to explain how we display a component using an array. But you are right we can add.